# how to set field attribute (limit) dynamically?

Tags: python, odoo-11

I have an One2many fields that have a requirement of setting limit,
I can set statics digits as `record_ids = fields.One2many('root.model', 'name' ,limit=10 )`.

This will only display 10 records.

But now I'd like to set this field for the user to change its limit.

I change its property as `limit = lambda self: self._record_limit()`
, and set a filed as `record_limit = fields.Integer(default=10)`.

```py
    stock_ids = fields.One2many('bs.stock.material.details', 'name', limit= lambda self:self._record_limit())
    record_limit = fields.Integer(default=10)

def _record_limit(self):
    return self.record_limit
```

I hope I can adjust the display number of the o2m field by setting the number of `record_limit` field.

For example, if I don't set record_limit, the o2m always display 10 record in the list. And If I set it to 20, the o2m can show 20 records.

but I got this error:

```
  File "D:\odoo\odoo11_boshown\odoo-11.0\odoo\models.py", line 1481, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo11_boshown\odoo-11.0\odoo\models.py", line 3810, in _search
    limit_str = limit and ' limit %d' % limit or ''
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not function
```

How can I set this limit dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set dynamic limit of One2many fields in odoo. 
You can use default method for display specific record. 
There are only two ways if you can give a number of records `static` for display records. 
Otherwise, you can add default method or use a domain for the apply filter in your One2many fields records.

In your code, you are using limit attribute wrong way.
the limit attribute accepts only integer values or numbers. But you are trying to pass iterable.